# Generic error occurred in GDI+ on 2nd Bitmap.Save method

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi+

I write a function which writes to a file, but each time it is called it will rewrite over the old file and replace it. However, it refuses to write over it the second time it runs. Closing the program resets this cycle.

I had a look around and noticed it is probably being blocked as it is still being used in the program. I guess the file was not disposed of correctly.

What I tried: Adding Using and Dispose to clear the memory to allow rewriting. However, it still does not want to write the file more than once.

This is what I ended up with:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile($"{ID}Image.png");
using (var newBitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Template.png")))
{
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
    {
        using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 18))
        {
            Font arialFont2 = new Font("Arial", 28);
            RectangleF Rectangle1 = new RectangleF(0, 350, 858, 40);
            RectangleF Rectangle2 = new RectangleF(0, 390, 858, 30);
            RectangleF Rectangle3 = new RectangleF(0, 420, 858, 30);
            RectangleF Rectangle4 = new RectangleF(0, 450, 858, 30);
            graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            graphics.DrawString(UserName, arialFont2, Brushes.Black, Rectangle1);
            graphics.DrawString("Info: " + LoadData(ID, "Info"), arialFont, Brushes.Black, Rectangle2);
            graphics.DrawString("Total: " + LoadData(ID, "Total"), arialFont, Brushes.Black, Rectangle3);
            graphics.DrawString("Other: " + LoadData(ID, "Other"), arialFont, Brushes.Black, Rectangle4);
            graphics.DrawImage(img, 525, 250);
            newBitmap.Save($"{ID}Stats.gif");
            arialFont.Dispose();
            arialFont2.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();
            newBitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't open the file elsewhere? This is really easy to do by accident (file system watcher, shell extensions...). Are you doing this in ASP.NET or Winforms? Does it help if you save the image to a memory stream first and then manually copy the stream to a file? Note that `Image.FromFile` does not create a copy of the image - it still refers to the original file, preventing it from being written to. Again, loading the file to memory first (and using the `byte[]` constructor) avoids that, or you can clone the image.

Comment: I'm sure I do not have it open anywhere else, and it's a .net console application. I will try to load it into a memory stream and see if that helps.

Comment: So I added memory stream and that still didn't work, so I decided to look around a bit and there was another `Image.FromFile` I guess it was open somewhere else, I didn't know how `FromFile` worked so I guess I just wasn't looking for it.Thankyou for the help.